# Can-bus driver of hcs12

Tags: c, embedded, driver, codewarrior, can-bus

Where can I find the following missing functions [here](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/BookSoftware/Chap14.c) in this HCS12 CAN driver?

```
CANFifo_Init()
CANFifo_Get(msg)
CANFifo_Put(msgPtr)
```

Comment: How can we tell? Where did you find the code that includes these calls?  Exactly what part are you using? Not all HCS12 have a CAN controller. Rather then rely on "mystery code" why not use the manufacturer's CAN library https://www.nxp.com/downloads/en/device-drivers/MSCAN_S12_DEVD.zip

Comment: Are you getting a linker error or a compiler error?  That is do you have the header but no library, or neither.  If you have the header you possibly have the library but have failed to link it or (if it is a source code library) failed to include the source in your project.

Comment: [link] (http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/BookSoftware/Chap14.c) @Clifford

Comment: Worst choice of function identifier yet, `CAN_Open`. No, it doesn't give you CANopen support, sorry :)

Comment: Anyway, questions asking where to find libraries and other off-site resources are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

The physical book *Embedded Microcomputer Systems: Real Time Interfacing* included a bound-in CD-ROM.  I imagine the code was on that perhaps.  Without access to the full text of the book or the CD-ROM content it is difficult to tell. Even on the authors own website, the link to the teaching materials is broken.

If you are doing this course, the course provider should provide all necessary materials.  If you are just wanting to write production CAN bus code for a specific part, I would not start with academic course material.